# Addition Assignment in Bash

Tags: bash, addition

In C++, if you have two variables a and b, you can do this to add b to a:

```
a += b;
```

How can you do the same thing in bash?

Comment: Bash also uses `+=` for string and array concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround the expression in double parenthesis, like so:

```
a=$(($a + $b))
```

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
(( a+= $b ))
```

or even:

```
let a+=$b
```

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, added that the the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter two numbers:"
read a b
let a+=$b
echo $a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `(( ... ))` syntax, you don't need to use `$` at all before most (simple) variables, so you can do:

```
a=$((a + b))
```

or

```
((a += b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `a +=b` is just `a = a + b`.

In bash, you can use the following syntax:

`a=$(($a+ $b))`